# How to plot the following Partial Sum?

Tags: plotting, summation

How can I plot: $$\sum_{n=1}^{400}\frac1{n^3\sin^2(n)}$$ without using the Table function? I am looking for a plot similar to the discrete plot in *Mathematica*. I am new to this software, I was able to complete the job with *Maple* and *MATLAB* but can't figure out how to do so in *Mathematica*. Thank you for any help!

$\textbf{MAPLE CODE:}$

```
L:=ListTools:-PartialSums([seq(1/((n^3)*(sin(n)^2)),n=1..400)]):
plots:-listplot(L,style=point);
```

$\textbf{MAPLE OUTPUT:}$

[image]

$\textbf{MATLAB OUTPUT:}$

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "plot the partial sum"? That sum is just a number, so what are you actually plotting? If you mean plot the *sequence*, then do look up `DiscretePlot`.

Comment: I mean by ploting the values of the given sum up to 400...

Comment: Can you share your try in Maple?

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal I forgot the paranthesis, now it should work

Comment: Would `ListPlot[Accumulate[Function[n, 1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2)] @ Range[400]], Filling -> Axis]` work for you?

Comment: @J.M. The output is similar to the one I am looking for, however it does not display the behavior from n=355 to 400

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it, is to use `Array`.

```
f[N1_] = Sum[1/(n^3*Sin[n]^2), {n, 1, N1}]
Array[f, {400}];
ListPlot[%, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The approach suggested by @J.M. in the comment is more efficient than this one.

```
ListPlot[Array[f, {400}], PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 1.03085

```
ListPlot[Accumulate[Function[n, 1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2)]@Range[400]], Filling -> Axis, 
PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 0.424839

Comment: The plot is not very clear, I will add the picture of the plots I am looking for (the ones i got with matlab and maple)

Comment: @DMH16 See the edit

Comment: You only need to add `Filling -> Axis`. This is a bit wasteful, tho, since terms are computed repeatedly in `Sum[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
partialSums = Accumulate[1/(#^3 Sin[#]^2) & /@ Range[400]];
```

Using [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)

```
ListLinePlot[partialSums, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

Using [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html)

```
ListLogPlot[partialSums, Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html) as mentioned by [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march):

```
f[N1_] = Sum[1/(n^3*Sin[n]^2), {n, 1, N1}];

DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]